# Converting label.tag as integer and then multiple it with input quantity

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i set lbl_harga for selected data from mysql data and data type is double for price. in this problem, i want to add selected data to listbox. when i try to insert the quantity, here's the main problem

i already try all available convert string to integer, but when there are no problem for quantity input. the multiple result become 0.00

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim qty1 As Integer = Val(InputBox("Jumlah yang ingin dibeli : ", "Jumlah"))

            If Not qty1 = 0 Then
                Dim total_harga As Integer = Int32.Parse(Me.lbl_harga.Tag) * qty1
                ListBox1.Items.Add(Me.lbl_id.Text + " - " + Me.lbl_judul.Text + " * " + Str(qty1) + "  :  " + Format(total_harga, "##,##0.00"))
                total_harga_belanja += total_harga
                Me.lbl_total.Text = total_harga_belanja
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

i set the data type for qty as int and price as double

message error that i get is

```
value cannot be null
Parameter name is: String
```

Comment: Isn't the `Tag` property type `Object`? In that case, you can just box an `Integer` into it, no need to `Parse` it, a simple `DirectCast` should do... no?

Comment: Did you debug your code? What value you have in `Me.lbl_harga.Tag` and `qty1`? What line of code gives the error ?

Comment: You're parsing the `.Tag` which is of type Object. Parse `Me.lbl_harga.Tag.ToString`. Set Option Explicit On and Option Strict On, in your Project. You should also handle cases where `.Tag` is Nothing.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: Please don't use Val. We have so many other more modern Functions that return what you need. Val is a legacy function leftover from VB6 days and has some weird behavior.